# Unable to round-trip ELF binaries (due to NULs?) with OpenSSL EVP_* functions

Tags: c, linux, openssl, filesystems, fuse

i have developed a cipher filesystem using FUSE. Using openSSL functions i cipher and decipher blocks of regular files without problem. The problem is when i cipher a binary file (ELF) beacuse it does not work and i do not know why. I use next code:

```
int encrypt_data_no_pad(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
        unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext, int algorithm_pos)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, ciphers[algorithm_pos].algorithm(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); //Quitamos el padding automatico

    /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int decrypt_data_no_pad(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
        unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext, int algorithm_pos)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    /* Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, ciphers[algorithm_pos].algorithm(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0); //Quitamos el padding automatico
    /* Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;
    /* Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}
```

It is a part of the code and i think the problem is the 0's byte in the elf files. I think these functions does not work with 0 byte in the middle of the plaintext. Could be that? Or do these functions work correctly anyway? In his case, the problem will be in the rest of the code and i will look for the bug there.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Easy to test whether your code is having trouble with NUL bytes -- create a non-ELF file that has some. `printf '%s\0' hello world >file`, and try round-tripping your file.

Comment: ...that said, the underlying OpenSSL functions are completely fine with them.

Comment: Anyhow -- in terms of coming up with a better place to start, I'd strongly suggest a minimal reproducer. *Minimal* might mean not even requiring any file I/O -- if the shortest possible thing that someone else can copy, paste and run without external dependencies to showcase your problem just encrypts and decrypts a hardcoded in-memory buffer, that might be the route to go. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).